# Marble problem (Logic)

Tags: logic

A and B have some marbles with them. When A gives 100 marbles to B,then the number odd marbles with B becomes double than that of A. When B gives some marbles to A them A has 5 times more marbles than B. What is the minimum number of marbles A and B can possibly have?

I solved it using hit and trial method got answer of 200 and 100 marbles respectively. Is this a correct answer?

Comment: I don't understand what "the number odd marbles with B" means.  What is an odd marble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try to minimize $B$.  It can be seen that by minimizing $B$ we will also minimize $A$.

---

Translating the conditions into equations, we are told that if $A$ gives 100 marbles to $B$ then $B$ will now have double the number of marbles that $A$ now has.

$(B+100) = 2(A-100)=2A-200$

Next, we are told that there is some number of marbles that $B$ can give to $A$ such that $A$ now has five times the number of marbles that $B$ now has.

$\exists n>0:~~~~5(B-n) = (A+n)$

Let's multiply the second equation by $2$ and subtract $200+2n$ from each side:

$10(B-n)-200-2n = 2A-200$ which we see is equal to what we had before of $B+100$

So, $10B-12n-200 = B+100$ and $9B = 12n+300$ and $3B = 4n+100$

We need $B$ to be an integer and we see that $B$ is minimized when $n$ is minimized.  The smallest positive $n$ could be that keeps $B$ an integer is then $2$, so $3B = 108$ and $B = 36$

With $B=36$, plugging back into the first equation, we get $A=168$

---

Checking:  Originally $A$ has $168$ marbles and $B$ has $36$ marbles.  After $A$ gives 100 marbles to $B$ we have that $A$ has $68$ marbles and $B$ has $136$ marbles, twice that of $A$.

Further, had $B$ given $A$ two marbles, $B$ would have been left with $34$ marbles and $A$ would have had $170$ marbles, five times that of $B$.

---

The answer you gave with $A=200$ and $B=100$ corresponded to $n=50$ and was not optimal, there being several smaller values of $n$ which could have been used.